# celery worker in kubernetes won't teminate while running in sh -c

Tags: kubernetes, celery, sh

I have an issue running celery worker using `sh`in kuberntes. How do I make the celery worker receive TERMSIG?

kubernetes Celery worker doesn't receive TERMSIG while running under `sh -c`
manifest example:

```yaml
...
command: [ 'sh']
args: [ '-c', 'celery --quiet -A ${CELERY_APP} worker --prefetch-multiplier 1 --loglevel ${WORKER_LOGLEVEL} --queues ${WORKER_QUEUE} -n ${WORKER_PREFIX}-${HOSTNAME} -c 1 2>&1' ]
...
```

When the pod terminates the worker doesn't indicate it received TERMSIG

Connecting to the pods and running `kill` terminates the worker normally.

if I run the worker like:

```yaml
...
command: ["celery"]
args: ["--quiet", "-A", "$(CELERY_APP)", "worker" , "--prefetch-multiplier", "1", "--loglevel", "$(WORKER_LOGLEVEL)", "--queues", "$(WORKER_QUEUE)", "-n", "$(WORKER_PREFIX)-$(HOSTNAME)"]
...
```

The shutdown works fine (Warm shutdown)

Comment: You did not really formulate a question, but shells typically (e.g bash) do not process signals while running an external command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sh` doesn't propagate signals to children.
I've end up using a bash script like specified at https://veithen.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html

propagating the signals manually

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'kill -TERM $PID; wait $PID' TERM INT

celery --quiet -A ${CELERY_APP} worker --prefetch-multiplier 1 --loglevel ${WORKER_LOGLEVEL} --queues ${WORKER_QUEUE} -n ${WORKER_PREFIX}-${HOSTNAME} -c 1 2>&1 &
PID=$!
wait $PID
wait $PID
EXIT_STATUS=$?
```